push nameserver to client with vpn windows built-in
I have configured an IKEv2 VPN with Windows-server 2022,
and defined a static range of IP addresses for then tunneling (192.168.1.0 -> 192.168.1.10).
Now, every client that connects will get 192.168.1.1 as ‘endpoint’.
Knowing that the Windows server (hosting the VPN server) does not have a dns/dhcp server, is it still possible to associate a name with this 192.168.1.1 address?
(A kind of push)
(I was thinking about mDNS, but I guess routing is not working with this tech.)
